# C# Saving and Pulling data from a file with Binary Serlialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am kind of at a loss at the moment on what to do. I'm trying to make an MVC project where I display items, kind of like a catalog. 
I want to be able to save the items in some sort of IEnumerable collection and then save that to a file. 
Then I want to be able to pull the data from the file and repopulate the IEnumerable collection with the items from the save file.

However, I'm encountering a problem where I'm not able to get any items back from the save file.

Here are my Saving and Loading methods:

```
public void SaveProducts(IEnumerable<Product> col)
    {
        Stream stream = File.Open("C:\\temp\\Products.txt", FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        bformatter.Serialize(stream, col);
        stream.Close();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        IEnumerable<Product> products;

        Stream stream = File.Open("C:\\temp\\Products.txt", FileMode.Open);
        BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        products = (IEnumerable<Product>)bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Close();


        return products;
    }
```

And then I've tried pulling the information back like this:

```
IEnumerable<Product> retrievedProducts = dal.GetProducts();

        this.products = retrievedProducts.ToList();

        foreach (Product p in products)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
        }

        dal.SaveProducts(products);
```

I don't quite know what is giving me the problem in pulling the items back from the file. My Console.WriteLine never prints anything, so there isn't anything being retrieved from the file itself it seems.

**EDIT**

My Product class:

```
  [Serializable()]
public class Product : ISerializable 
{
    public static int nextId = 1;
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a price")]
    public float ListPrice { get; set; }

     public Product()
    {
        Id = nextId++;
    }


     public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
     {
         info.AddValue("Id", Id);
         info.AddValue("Name", Name);
         info.AddValue("Desc", Description);
         info.AddValue("Price", ListPrice);
     }

     public Product(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
     {
         Id = (int)info.GetValue("Id", typeof(int));
         Name = (string)info.GetValue("Name", typeof(string));
         Description = (string)info.GetValue("Desc", typeof(string));
         ListPrice = (float)info.GetValue("Price", typeof(float));
     }
}
```

Comment: Is there any data being saved to the file?

Comment: The text file has content in it, so I believe it is being saved, yes

Comment: If you are doing this from an ASP.NET application, the identity you are running under may not have access to the location C:\. I've tried your code and it works perfectly in a console application

Comment: I was having trouble saving to the file earlier due to access issues, but I thought I had managed to resolve those. Is there any way I can get this to work?

Comment: Can you attach a debugger and see what is the response of bformatter.Deserialize(stream) before casting?

Comment: @Sarathy I do not know how I would see what the response is before casting, as it is null before I deserialize it and it has to be casted then.

Comment: You do not have to cast the response. BinaryFormatter includes type information while serializing. If the response is null before deserialization, then it would be a different issue.

Comment: @Sarathy If I do not cast it, it throws an error because it cannot implicitly convert the object to an IEnumerable. What could the issue be?

Comment: As Set mentioned, could you check the source of the data before saving?

Answer (score 0):

1. Is Product class marked as  [Serializable] ?
2. Try to add [ToList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) before you call serialize:

   bformatter.Serialize(stream, col.ToList());

Are you sure that when you call dal.GetProducts() you really have data in file? In other words, are you call dal.SaveProducts(products) somewhere before calling GetProducts() method?

I have tested your code using the following, and it is working...

```
        var products = new List<Product>();
        products.Add(new Product() { Name = "product1" });
        products.Add(new Product() { Name = "product2" });
        dal.SaveProducts(products);
        var data = dal.GetProducts();
```

Comment: Yes it is, and I tried adding ToList but I still did not get anything back.

Comment: I call SaveProducts(products) every time I add a new product to the list, but it still does not update.

Comment: When I have a hardcoded item in the list, and I try to save and then pull that data from the file, it returns nothing at all. It does not even display the hardcoded product.

Comment: try to save to another file in another directory

Comment: I keep getting a filenotfound exception even when the file is there

Answer (score 0):

I have tryied to reproduce your issue, but for me it works:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DAL dal = new DAL();

        var products = dal.GetInitialProducts().ToList();

        foreach (Product p in products)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", p.Name, p.Id, p.Description, p.ListPrice);
        }

        dal.SaveProducts(products);

        IEnumerable<Product> retrievedProducts = dal.GetProducts();

        Console.WriteLine("\nRetrieved Products");
        foreach (Product p in retrievedProducts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", p.Name, p.Id, p.Description, p.ListPrice);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I have added in the DAL object the following method:

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetInitialProducts()
{
        List<Product> list = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product{Name = "First", Description = "descr1", Id = 1, ListPrice = 1.1F},
            new Product{Name = "Second", Description = "descr2", Id = 2, ListPrice = 2.2F},
        };
            return list;
}
```